# Do Indian citizens need transit visa for Thailand if going through DMK?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, thailand, dmk

I am traveling from Chennai to Don Mueang International Airport, Bangkok, Thailand, and from there to Mandalay, Myanmar. In Bangkok, the layover time is 8 hours. Do I require transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

Airlines use the [Timatic database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) to determine what documents, if any, must be provided by an embarkinig passenger. Airlines are very careful about this, as passengers refused entry at a destination must be returned to the passenger's point of departure at the airline's expense.

Timatic is available on the web [here](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html).

Entering your nationality, destination, and stopover point yields this report:

[image: Timatic Report]

The report indicates that if you're traveling on a single ticket on Thai Air Asia or Thai Air Asia X, and your onward flight is within 12 hours of your arrival, then you do not need a Transit Visa. If you are traveling on another carrier (those listed in the "TWOV" or "Transit Without Visa" section), or on two different carriers, then you do need a Transit Visa.